# WordPress 5.5 'breaks' CiviCRM frontend pages without upgrade to 5.26+

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, paypal, mailchimp, webhook

The links in our renewal notifications stopped working following the automatic site upgrade to Wordpress 5.5 on Aug 11th. What happened is that the links just arrived at the 'Wordpress Base Page', in our case /civicrm, with a meaningless “Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM.”

Spent some time investigating before finding the notification of a mandatory update to CiviCRM 5.26, and this did indeed sort the problem. [Important Notice blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice)

Posting here in case others also searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front end links working again after upgrade to 5.28.2.

Note that there was also an update needed to our Mailchimp webhook for linked groups. Simply done by saving the group settings.

Fingers crossed the Paypal payment IPN link is still good to go.

Comment: The paypal IPN worked in most cases.   To be sure, set up a 307 redirect as detailed https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733507/4667333

Comment: THere is also a note of caution for users of GoCardless to do the civi upgrade before the WP upgrade to avoid webhook errors - may be other third party providers affected too